# Send Viewmodel with list to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, controller, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm trying to submit my viewmodel with complex types, to my controller, but my viewmodel is null when it hits the controller.

[image: Formdata in request in Network tab(chrome)]

Here is the relevant code from my view:

```
@model ShoppingCartViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Indkøbskurv";
}

<h2>Indkøbskurv</h2>
<form method="post" asp-controller="ShoppingCart" asp-action="SaveProductsHistory">

    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:30px">
        <div class="col-md-9"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <button type="submit" id="saveAndDeleteShoppingCart" class="btn btn-warning">Gem og slet kurv  <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Produktnavn</th>
                <th>Varenummer</th>
                <th>Antal</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Products.Count(); i++)
            {               
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" asp-for="Products[i].Product.id" />
                            <input type="text" asp-for="Products[i].Product.area" />
                            <input type="text" asp-for="Products[i].Product.eurofinsItemNumber" />
                            <input type="text" asp-for="Products[i].Product.internetAddress" />
                            <input type="text" asp-for="Products[i].Product.ourResponsibility" />
                            <input type="text" asp-for="Products[i].Product.productNameEnvAir" />
                            <input type="text" asp-for="Products[i].Product.productNameSupplier" />
                            <input type="text" asp-for="Products[i].Product.storageSize" />
                            <input type="text" asp-for="Products[i].Product.storageType" />
                            <input type="text" asp-for="Products[i].Product.supplierName" />
                            <input type="text" asp-for="Products[i].Product.supplierProductNumber" />
                            <input type="text" asp-for="Products[i].Product.supplierProductNumberInfo" />
                            <input type="text" asp-for="Products[i].Product.unit" />
                            <input type="text" asp-for="Products[i].Quantity" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a class="adjust-button dec" aria-label="Decrease quantity" href="#">-</a>
                        <input class="adjust-input" value="@Model.Products[i].Quantity">
                        <input id="productID" type="hidden" value="@Model.Products[i].Product.id" />
                        <a class="adjust-button inc" aria-label="Increase quantity" href="#">+</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="removeProductFromCookies"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

along with my action on my controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public void SaveProductsHistory(ShoppingCartViewModel shoppingCartViewModels)
        {}
```

and my viewmodel

```
public class ShoppingCartViewModel
    {
        public List<ShoppingCartViewModelItem> Products;

        public ShoppingCartViewModel()
        {
            Products = new List<ShoppingCartViewModelItem>();
        }
    }
```

My view displays the data from my viewmodel just fine, and it seems like everything is sent over correctly, from inspecting the first picture in this post, but I still receive null when it hits my controller.

Comment: try with [FromForm] attribute in your action method

    [HttpPost]
    public void SaveProductsHistory([FromForm] ShoppingCartViewModel shoppingCartViewModels)
        {}

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but as far as I know, [FromForm] isn't used in asp.net core 2, as it is the default expected input anyway. It does make it more verbose, in case other developers read your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to expose `Products` as a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) not [field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) in your `ShoppingCartViewModel` class, that is making the object `null` as model binder need public setter to fill the model back at post.

Change:

```
public List<ShoppingCartViewModelItem> Products;
```

to:

```
public List<ShoppingCartViewModelItem> Products { get; set; }
```

### Edit:

Another thing i am not sure if `asp-for="Products[i].Product.id"` works or not, but normally it is provided like `asp-for="Model.Products[i].Product.id"`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Had to put { get; set; } on all properties, on my ShoppingCartViewModelItem as well. Thanks!